# Search word in word list text file in android

Tags: java, search, file-io, cpu-word

Friends I have a list of words sorted out alphabetically in a text file(2MB) containing 300,000 words (1 word per line). Since it is already sorted, I want to make a quick string search which has to be exact and case insensitive. Any ideas how to do that?

Gotta make it as quick as possible and case insensitive. For instance,

If user needs to search word 'MAT' from the text file, the output must be mat/MAT and should not include mate, matted or any such words. The output should be generated in the least time.

EDIT -  I need a solution like a class or algorithm to do it like Pattern/matcher or BufferedReader/Scanner, etc.

Comment: Uh, shouldn't you use a database for this?

Comment: create a whole database with just 1 column? and the over-heads might be more than searching a text file

Comment: The over heads are worth it, considering the improves search speed. You could even cut it down by having a tablet per alphabet, and searching only that table based on the first alphabet of user input.

Comment: just for simplicity and saving the time, i need to make quick search through the text file only although you are right about making different tables for each alphabet

Answer (score 1):

If your word list is already sorted the fastest way I can think of is using the [binary search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm). As for the case sensitive part, just apply a ToUpper() or ToLower() on each string (the input one, and the one to compare with in your file) and problem solved.

Although I agree with the others, you should just use a database for this.

Answer (score 0):

Your best way is probably to store it properly into a database, in such a way you have to search through the least amount of data.

Per example a table per alphabetical letter, with only words starting with that letter. 
Basically that already cuts a search into like 300,000 / 20 (26 - minus some rare letters with very few words).

That would probably already do it for 300,000 words, but if not you can even take it further and make some length separations.

Saving all your words into the database might take a while though, but that might not be a problem for your app.